# Is there free pipeline shapefile data for Asia?

Tags: data, oil-gas, asia

I need to find oil & gas pipeline data in the world especially about Asia but I want to get them freely.

Comment: That's generally considered to be sensitive information.

Comment: I don't know why this question is downvoted so heavily. This is a valid question even if someone might be interested in not disclosing such information.

Comment: I agree with you.I could find this information in UK and all part of Africa freely.but this is not enough for me.

Comment: @SS_Rebelious I suspect the downvotes have been placed because the asker has not included any details of their research prior to asking.

Comment: It is still in Beta but I think questions related to obtaining Open Data may be better asked on the [Open Data Stack Exchange](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/) where there is a [geospatial](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geospatial) tag available.

Answer (score 2):

I just googled and found some links may need a look

- http://www.theodora.com/pipelines/asia_oil_gas_and_products_pipelines.html
- http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Pipeline_data_sources
- http://enipedia.tudelft.nl/wiki/Oil_and_Gas_Map

Comment: Thank you for your attention,but I can't download any data in these sites.

Comment: there are several types of data in these links, go to the third link and click a "GeoTiff or WMS layer" and there you can download data as kml map.. and open kml in google earth.

Comment: I tried to download kml format and converted it to .shp in ArcGIS,but in this site there is just image and I could not convert it.Any way, thank you so much.

Comment: Yes these are map (as i said "download data as kml map") to convert them into shapefile you need exerting a bit labor- but the plus point is these maps are georeferenced one.

Answer (score 0):

These 2 sites have oil and gas  pipeline locations in various formats:
http://worldmap.harvard.edu/data/geonode:natural_gas_pipelines_j96
http://worldmap.harvard.edu/data/geonode:global_oil_pipelines_2_36s